# What is the reverse of tail -c +K?

Tags: tail

I was reading this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20161138/54964). The command `tail -c +K /tmp/1` outputs bytes starting with the Kth of each file. 
From `man tail`

```
   -c, --bytes=K
          output the last K bytes; alternatively,  use  -c  +K  to  output
          bytes starting with the Kth of each file
```

I would like to find any tool which does this reverse i.e. start to read from the end of the file and read to the beginning of the file.

How can you do the reverse of `tail -c +K`?

Comment: You do say *"start to read from the end … to the beginning …"*. – Do you mean that all the data is reversed?  -ie.  *`abc\n`* becomes *`\ncba`*

Comment: No possibility to reverse the data. You can assume the data size is 1 TB. On the other hard, when you read in reverse direction, the data seems to be reversed. So yes, the data should be read as \ncba...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [GNU head](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/head-invocation.html), you can use:

```
head -c K
```

to output the first K bytes of file.

---

```
head -c -0 file
```

also output all bytes in file but doesn't read from the end to the beginning.

Comment: Why `head -c -0 file` and not just `cat file`?

Comment: @petry: It will help the OP to gain the whole picture about that `head` can do all the reverse of `tailf` he asked.

Comment: This returns the data in the normal reading direction. I file abc\n. It reads abc\n. It reads from the start of the file until the specific mark. I want from the specific mark to the start of the file.

Comment: @Masi: If the original data is `1234ABCD`, then `tail -c +4` outputs `4ABCD`  ... and  `head -c -3` outputs `1234A` -- Is this what you want?

Comment: @Peter.O Otherwise `head -c -3` is ok but everything should read from the reverse direction like A4321. To actually reverse the data and then just read can be too expensive process. To just read in reverse direction is wanted.